# Is there a way to target a specific element using Puppeteer AND preserve the CSS when converting html to pdf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, headless, google-chrome-headless

I'd like to convert **some** html to a pdf file. The problem is that I just need a part of a webpage and most certainly not all elements. So I was wondering if there is a way to target a single element with a specific `id` for example, so that only that element gets converted to a pdf?

I know I can do this for example:

```
const dom = await page.$eval('div.jsb', (element) => {
     return element.innerHTML
}) // Get DOM HTML
await page.setContent(dom)   // HTML markup to assign to the page for generate pdf
```

However, using the code above won't preserve the CSS...

It is also not an option to use `page.addStyleTag` to add the css by hand, since the element I am trying to convert to a pdf has loads and loads of CSS styles already applied to it...

So the question remains, how can I convert a single element on a page using Puppeteer (or if you know of other ways / methods / libraries, then those are welcome too of course).

[Grabzit](https://grabz.it/api/nodejs/grabzitclient.aspx#pdfoptions) for example allows to you to specify the `targetElement` in their options like so:

```
const options = {
   'targetElement': '#rightContent',
   'pagesize': 'A4',
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not give me consistent results.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the same requirement!

Answer (score 0):

I have had some success like this:

```
const myElement = await page.$('.my-el');
await page.evaluate(el => {
  el = el.cloneNode(true);

  document.body.innerHTML = `
    <div>
      ${el.outerHTML}
    </div>
  `;
}, myElement);
const pdf = await page.pdf(...)
```

However it is not working  very well when the element I select contains Canvas elements.

(Code based on example here https://github.com/puppeteer/examples/blob/master/element-to-pdf.js)